# Activiti User task candidate groups property field deletion not happening

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I have created a new process diagram and it contains a user task. I have written properties for the user task, and mentioned a candidate group value.

[Activiti user guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html)

Now i an trying to delete that value for the candidate groups field but i am not able to do that. Every time i changed that and saved, it not reflecting the deletion next time i open it.

I have to delete the process diagram every time an create a new one.

Updated : To give examples i have to add couple of images, because it's all about diagram as per activiti BPMN process is concerned.

[image: Peocess Diagram]

And i have added the properties of EmployeeTask as shown :

[image: Employee Task properties]

Comment: Can you please provide us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many a times but failed to do so, then i wrote to a person from Activiti group regading the issue. He told its a bug in this version of Activiti i.e `Activiti 5.12` and they are going to fix this "bug" in the next release. To give the exact details they have already resolved the `JIRA` task that i had raised.

Lets wait for next release to get this issue resolved.